# Insert list of values into database with persistent

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

Assuming I have this code (simplified from ["Synopsis"](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent))

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persist|
Person
  name String
|]

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ runSqlConn $ do
  runMigration migrateAll

  johnID <- insert $ Person "John Doe"
  janeID <- insert $ Person "Jane Doe"

  liftIO $ print johnID
  liftIO $ print janeID

  return ()

input = [Person "John Doe", Person "Jane Doe"]
```

How would I insert the list `input` and in turn receive a list of IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [forM](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v%3aforM) function into `runSqlConn` block. For example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ runSqlConn $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

    ids <- forM input insert
    liftIO $ print ids

  where
    input = [Person "John Doe", Person "Jane Doe"]
```

Comment: Or more haskellish, `mapM insert input`. I know RWH has a discussion why there is both `mapM` and `forM`.

Comment: Hmm, works. Tried that before and it spew out weird error messages. Thank you.